# How to display the fetched data only once inside a loop

Tags: php, html, sql

I want the **1st Semester S.Y 2013** to display only once. But in my code it is displayed multiple times because it's inside the loop. Is there any alternative ways to do it?

Here's the output of my code.
[image]

here's the looping

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">

  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>Subject Code</th>
      <th>Decription</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th>Units</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
                          $sql ="SELECT * FROM grades WHERE stud_no ='$stud_no'";
                           $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                   
  ?>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['semester']. "st Semester S.Y " .$row['sch_year'];?></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['subj_cd'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['subj_descr'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['final_grade'];?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['units_lec'] + $row['units_lab'];?></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
   $sql ="SELECT * FROM grades WHERE stud_no ='$stud_no'";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  var $check=1; //added line
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                   
  ?>
```

Then use a if-condition to achieve your objective

```
<td><?php
if($check==1){
echo $row['semester']. "st Semester S.Y " .$row['sch_year'];
$check=0;
}
?></td>
```